# typeahead.js returns "blank" dataset

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I have a bit of an issue with twitters [typeAhead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) returning blank results and the official doc's are not helping either.

**what am i expecting:**

```
<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">Warcraft II: Tides of Darkness</div>
...
```

**What is happening:**

When typing in the input field, typeAhead returns empty html like so, the list does populate according to how many results are fetched, so it is working

```
<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"></div>
<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"></div>
<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"></div>
<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"></div>
<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"></div>
```

**My code:**

```
var gameTitles= new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '../api/autocomplete/%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#title').typeahead({minLength: 3}, {
  name: 'game-titles',
  display: 'value',
  source: gameTitles
});
```

and for reference the remote returns the following so I know for certain my query gets passed on correctly

```
[
  "Warcraft II: Tides of Darkness",
  "Warcraft II: Beyond the Dark Portal",
  "Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos",
  "Warcraft II: The Dark Saga",
  "Peggle: World of Warcraft Edition",
  "Warcraft III: Reforged Spoils of War Edition",
  "World of Warcraft",
  "Warcraft III: Reforged",
  "Warcraft: Orcs & Humans",
  "World of Warcraft: Legion"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typeahead looks for objects in an array and by default for the suggestion is looking for `value` in those objects, this can be changed by assigning the name of the property you wish to be used to the `display` property

```
$('#title').typeahead({}, {
  name: 'game-titles',
  display: 'WHATEVER PROPERTY YOU WISH DISPLAYED',
  source: gameTitles
});
```

additionally, typeAhead is no longer being maintained, selectize.js seems to be a good alternative